# Showing that the Hopf fibration is a non-trivial fibre bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, group-cohomology, hopf-fibration, obstruction-theory

I want to show that the Hopf bundle
$$ \mathbb{S}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{S^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$$
is non-trivial as a principal fibre bundle.

I have seen hints of several different approaches:

1. Hopfs original approach, using linking numbers, see [Hopf fibration and $\pi_3(\mathbb{S}^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601157/hopf-fibration-and-pi-3-mathbbs2).
2. Hopf invariant.
3. Cohomology.

I want to keep it simple. My gut says cohomology is my best bet (I am slightly familiar with de Rahm Cohomology). Unfortunately, I am having trouble finding sources that treat this on my level (without a lot of general theory I *think* I don't need).

I have the following books:

1. *The Topology of Fibre Bundles*, Steenrod.
2. *Fibre Bundles*, Husemoller.
3. *Manifold and Differential Geometry*, Jeffry Lee.

What is the bare minimum of theory I need to to get to this result? What route would you advise?

I am an undergraduate working on a Bsc thesis.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easier way to show that is to remark that $\pi_1(S_3)=1$ and $\pi_1(S_2\times S_1)=Z$.

Comment: What does the notation $\pi_1(S_3)$ mean?

Comment: The fundamental group