# Fibration over a simply connected manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds with $N$. Is a locally trivial fibration $f:M\to N$ is globally trivial if $N$ is simply connected?

Comment: You need $N$ to be contractible if you want your fibration to be trivial.

Comment: Could you give me a reference for the proof of this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, consider for example the Hopf fibration. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration

[Showing that the Hopf fibration is a non-trivial fibre bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793967/showing-that-the-hopf-fibration-is-a-non-trivial-fibre-bundle)