# Geometric perspective to see that the Hopf-fibration is non-trivial.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I'm holding a seminar in geometry on the Hopf-fibration $S^3\rightarrow S^2$ using Quaternions/Rotations of $3$-Space to introduce the map. I've found a nice geometric way of presenting everything, except for the fact that the Hopf-fibration is not trivial.

I'd like to present that too geometrically (under stereographic projection). For instance, in the case of the Mobius strip, you can see that it is non-trivial by holding it next to a cylinder and noting that you need to tear it in at least one place to deform it into the said cylinder with **one** map, but you don't need to tear it if you allow **two** maps.

Following that analogy, I think the key is properly understanding the implications of every Hopf fiber being linked with the unit circle in the plane, but I can't visualize this properly.

Is there a nice way to see that we need at least two trivializing maps geometrically?

EDIT: It is common to refer to fiber bundles as twisted products, is there some visible "twisting" here?

Comment: If your audience is familiar with fundamental groups, the following answer by @Tsemo Aristide is the simplest that I can find so far. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1793990/481770

Comment: @TeebroProkash sadly they are not, it sure would make life easier! Perhaps you could help with my comment under Andrew's comment though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking of pairs of complex numbers rather than quaternions, let's write $(z_{1}, z_{2}) = (x_{1} + iy_{1}, x_{2} + iy_{2})$. One approach is to consider the *hemisphere*
$$
|z_{1}|^{2} + (\operatorname{Re} z_{2})^{2}
= x_{1}^{2} + y_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}
= 1,\quad y_{2} = 0,\quad x_{2} \geq 0.
$$
If $z_{2} = |z_{2}|e^{i\theta}$ is non-zero, then the Hopf circle through a point $(z_{1}, z_{2})$ of the $3$-sphere hits this hemisphere at $(e^{-i\theta}z_{1}, |z_{2}|)$. This shows the Hopf fibration is trivial on the open hemisphere. On the other hand, the boundary $\{z_{2} = 0\}$ of the hemisphere is a Hopf circle, so the action by scalar multiplication does not extend trivially to the boundary, but instead collapses the boundary to a point.

---

Another approach is to split the $3$-sphere into two solid tori by the Clifford torus $|z_{1}| = |z_{2}| = \frac{1}{2}$, and show that each is trivial as a circle bundle over a disk but the attaching map on the boundary glues latitudes of one solid torus to meridians of the other, so the union is not a trivial bundle.

Comment: I find your notation a bit hard to understand intuitively, but it seems to me that the first argument should be "visible" under stereographic projection, could you perhaps drop a line or two on that?

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely how I visualize this, too. 
For the first argument, please note that the Hopf fibration is just $(z_1,z_2)\mapsto [z_1:z_2]$, thereafter identifying $\mathbb{C}P^1$ with $S^2$. I feel like you see this already.

Comment: I have been playing around with my visualization to see the effect you describe. You can see the Hopf-circles intersecting the hemisphere of $S^2$. I don't understand why this makes it locally trivial though, as the Hopf-map of the great circles is clearly not this intersection in general. @TeebroProkash

Comment: Really sleepy. Can I return to this tomorrow? Apologies.

Comment: FWIW, if $C$ denotes the boundary circle of the closed hemisphere, the fact that every Hopf circle except $C$ intersects the open hemisphere $H^+$ in one point tells us there is a mapping from $H^+ \times S^1$ into the $3$-sphere whose image is the complement of $C$, and the action is trivial on the first factor, so the restriction of the Hopf bundle to the complement of $C$ is trivial.