# Using Hopf fibration to calculate $\pi_{3} (S^2)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-writing, fundamental-groups, fibration, hopf-fibration

The question says:

Theorems of Hurewicz and Hopf say that for $k < n, \pi_{k}(S^n)=1$ and $\pi_{n}(S^n)\cong \mathbb{Z}$. Assuming this for the moment, use the Hopf fibration $\eta : S^3 \rightarrow S^2$ with fibre $S^1$ to calculate $\pi_{3} (S^2).$

**My question is:**

How is the answer of this question different from the answer of the one in the following link [Hopf fibration and $\pi_3(\mathbb{S}^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601157/hopf-fibration-and-pi-3-mathbbs2)? I feel like my question is much easier, could anyone give me a hint and an outline for the solution please?

Comment: Do you know anything about the long exact sequence of homotopy groups induced by a fibration?  In particular, you have an exact sequence $$\{1\}\cong \pi_3(S^1)\to \pi_3(S^3)\to \pi_3(S^2)\to \pi_2(S^1)\cong \{1\}.$$

Comment: yes I know .... but I do not know the link between my question and them ..... could you explain this for me please?@WETutorialSchool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $F\to E\to B$ be a fibration.  Then we have the following long exact sequence of homotopy groups
$$\ldots \to \pi_{n+1}(B)\to \pi_n(F)\to \pi_n(E)\to \pi_n(B)\to \pi_{n-1}(F)\to\ldots.$$
In particular, for the Hopf fibration $S^1\to S^3\to S^2$, we obtain
$$\ldots \to \pi_{n}(S^1)\to \pi_n(S^3)\to \pi_n(S^2)\to \pi_{n-1}(S^2)\to \ldots.\ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

We know that $\pi_n(S^1)=\Bbb Z$ for $n=1$ and $\pi_n(S^1)=\{1\}$ for $n>1$.  Hence when $n\ge 3$, (1) looks like
$$\ldots\to \{1\} \to \pi_n(S^3)\to \pi_n(S^2) \to \{1\}\to\ldots.$$
Since the sequence is exact, we conclude that
$$\pi_n(S^3)\cong \pi_n(S^2)\ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
for all $n\ge 3$.

Now the Hurewicz theorem gives us $\pi_3(S^3)=\Bbb Z$.  So (2) means that
$$\pi_3(S^2)\cong \Bbb Z.$$

Comment: Could you look at that question, please?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3379122/show-that-pi-nb-is-isomorphic-to-pi-ne

Comment: Could you please tell me what theorem in Allen Hatcher that tell me if I have a vibration then I have the mentioned long exact sequence?

Comment: From where did you get this information  $\pi_n(S^1)=\{1\}$ for $n>1$. ?

Comment: To answer your first question, you can find this in Theorem 4.41 on page 376 of Hatcher's book (https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf).

Comment: To answer your second question, there is a fibration $\Bbb Z\to \Bbb R\to S^1$ (which?).  Then, use the same argument as above, we have the exact sequence $$\ldots \to \pi_n(\Bbb Z)\to \pi_n(\Bbb R) \to \pi_n(S^1) \to \pi_{n-1}(\Bbb Z) \to \ldots.\ \ \ \ \ (3)$$  Because $\Bbb Z$ is a discrete topological space, $\pi_n(\Bbb Z)=\{1\}$ for all positive integers $n$, and because $\Bbb R$ is contractible, $\pi_n(\Bbb R)=\{1\}$ for all positive integers $n$.  Thus (3) looks like $$\ldots\to\{1\}\to \{1\} \to \pi_n(S^1) \to \{1\}\to\ldots$$ for $n>1$.  The rest is all yours.

Comment: this fibration occurs when $n=1$ .... correct?

Comment: but still I do not understand how your answer answers my question

Comment: Sorry I got it :)) thanks!

Comment: Hmm??  The fibration has nothing to do with $n$ (presumably, you are referring to $n$ in $\pi_n$).

Comment: frankly know which fibre is this.

Comment: You mean you don't know which fibre $\Bbb Z\to \Bbb R\to S^1$ I was referring to?  It is given by $p:\Bbb R\to S^1$ sending $t\mapsto e^{2\pi t}$.